# App that allows adding lines boxes and text on top of images

Tags: applications

I am searching for an app that allows easily annotating pictures (mainly screenshots).
I've tried shutter but editing feature requires adding a package that is not in apt and I gave up.
Then I tried Flameshot and it looked like it has all the things I need but it can't save files. (they should appear under ~/Pictures/Screenshots but they don't).

I am wondering if maybe there is a curated app that allows drawing circles and adding text to images?

Comment: Shutter is awesome. You should be able to get it installed. What file are you having issues with? Follow these directions [here](https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/) and it'll most likely work for you - you can download the files from there. I personally use those same exact files and will personally vouch for their safety. I am pretty sure Shutter works directly with the Ubuntu 20.04 repos (add universe) so that will probably get filtered down to the next new version of eOS - but don't quote me on that as I'm not an eOS dev or anything.

Comment: Yeah, I was not comfortable downloading .deb files. Maybe I should. Anyway, if there was a nicely done curated app, it'd be awesome :P

Comment: I love Shutter. The good news is that I *think* the next version of eOS will have the updated repositories and Shutter will come downstream. With the newer repos, it installed and had the edit and upload functions all built in and working properly without any additional effort. Go ahead and download those .deb files. It's easiest to install them with "gdebi" if you're curious. You can also 'sudo apt install ./foo.deb'. I am 100% certain that they are not malicious files.

Comment: I prefer ksnip (https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip) over the Shutter, you should try it.

Comment: @Guest That is perfect! It has all the functionality I need and it installs cleanly from flatpak without issues :) If you want, you can change your comment into an answer so I can accept it :)